# Rails Installation PATH Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I am a beginner at this sort of stuff though I do have some knowledge of the Command Line through Codecademy's course.

While setting up my Ruby/Rails environment I got the following message in terminal after running
`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` from [installrails.com/steps/install_rvm_and_ruby](http://installrails.com/steps/install_rvm_and_ruby) :

```
Upgrade Notes:

/Users/aristotle/.bash_profile:1:export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

* WARNING: Above files contains `PATH=` with no `$PATH` inside, this can break RVM,
for details check https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525
to avoid this warning append #PATH.
* No new notes to display.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually written here https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525

Just make sure you have your variables exported accordingly.